# regex to match xml tags not containing other tags

Tags: xml, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I want to look for XML like this:

```xml
<Address>
    <Street>Windsor</Street>
</Address>
```

and I do not want to match XML like this:

```xml
<Address>
    <Number>15</Number>
    <Street>Windsor</Street>
</Address>
```

That is, **I am looking for addresses where the `Address` node does *not* contain a `Number` tag.**

I tried patterns like

```
<Address>(?!Number)</Address>
```

or

```
<Address>.*?(?!Number).*?</Address>
```

But I can't quite figure it out :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help to show the valid regex that you have tried so far, and what language you are using to see if there are regex restrictions

Comment: What programming language is this for? You should add it to the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Address>(?:(?!<Address>)(?!<Number>).)*</Address>
```

Warning: that assumes that you either have no newlines in your text, or that `.` can cross newline boundaries, the so-call `/s` or `DOTALL` mode, which `(?s)` will enable in some regex languages.